# Switching between function implementations with function pointers

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

I have two versions of a C function that trade off from each other in terms of speed and memory usage. These functions are located in a .cpp file which is shared across several programs. I want to use a function pointer so that I can switch back and forth between the two implementations, and have those changes carry through across all the files in my program.

Combination.h (extract)

```
long chooseRecursive (int n, int r);
long chooseLookup (int n, int r);
void foo (int n, int r);
static long (*choose)(int, int) = chooseRecursive;
```

Combination.cpp (extract)

```
long chooseRecursive (int n, int r) { cerr << "Recursive\n"; }
long chooseLookup (int n, int r) { cerr << "Lookup\n"; }
void foo (int n, int r) { choose(n, r); }
```

Main.cpp (extract)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv []) {
    choose = chooseLookup;
    choose(10, 5);
    foo(10, 5);
}
```

The output is:

```
Lookup
Recursive
```

Why does the foo function not use chooseLookup instead of chooseRecursive? How do I fix this? Is there a better approach I can use to accomplish the same goal?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: For C++, you might want to look at [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). It allows you to use member functions and lambda expressions as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As things stand, each .cpp file which includes Combination.h has its own `static` variable `choose`.  Your code in `main` updates main.cpp's copy but not the version in Combination.cpp.

One easy way to fix this is to change Combination.h to declare `choose` as `extern`

```
extern long (*choose)(int, int);
```

then implement/initialise this in Combination.cpp

```
long (*choose)(int, int) = chooseRecursive;
```

Comment: Thank you - that's what I suspected was happening. Is there a way to make `choose` a global variable that is shared everywhere?

Comment: @AndrewBaker Our edits must have overlapped.  I've updated my answer to cover changing `choose` to be global